# Group By with codeigniter doesn't work with empty records

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm having a problem with the Codeigniter.

I have three tables, the first "videos" contains all the videos, the second "video_author" contains all authors and the third "videos_views" contains the views of the videos.

I need to select all the videos of the first table, do a join on second table and do a join on the third table, until there everything works normal with the code below:

```
    $total_records = $this->db->count_all_results('videos');
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('videos');
    $this->db->where('videos_publication', '1');
    $this->db->join('video_author','video_author.video_author_id=videos.videos_author_id','left');
    $this->db->where('videos_id >=', $total_records - 20);
    $this->db->join('videos_views','videos_views.videos_views_id=videos.videos_id','left');
    $this->db->order_by("videos_views_total","desc");        
    $this->db->limit(20);
    $query_result = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query_result->result();
    return $result;
```

But I need to do a SELECT SUM to count the views of the videos tables and after a groupby to group the data according to the month, the biggest problem is that if you do not have a record on the views table, none value returns.

Code I'm using:

$total_records = $this->db->count_all_results('videos');

```
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('videos');
    $this->db->where('videos_publication', '1');
    $this->db->join('video_author','video_author.video_author_id=videos.videos_author_id','left');
    $this->db->where('videos_id >=', $total_records - 20);
    $this->db->join('videos_views','videos_views.videos_views_id=videos.videos_id','left');
    $this->db->select('SUM(videos_views_total)');
    $this->db->group_by('MONTH(videos_views_date)');
    $this->db->group_by('videos_views_id');
    $this->db->order_by("videos_views_total","desc");        
    $this->db->limit(20);
    $query_result = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query_result->result();
    return $result;
```

if the table "videos_views" has the records, it returns perfectly.

Every help is welcome

Comment: Do you ever plan to change to a different type of database? Because if not, you can easily write real sql and insert it into `$this->db->query();`. Then you won't have this mess.

Comment: can you clarify the actual return value. is it NULL or void (doens't return anything). and what is your expected output

Comment: Have you tried writing this as actual SQL in your DB to see if it returns results? I find it easier writing actual SQL then converting it to Active Record in CodeIgniter.